# Error in the use of the function library from JNI

Tags: java

When I run this code:

```
package jni_2;

public class Min2 {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("kernel32");
    }

    public native long FlushProcessWriteBuffers();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Min2 c = new Min2();
        c.FlushProcessWriteBuffers();
    }
}
```

I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jni_2.Min2.FlushProcessWriteBuffers()J
    at jni_2.Min2.FlushProcessWriteBuffers(Native Method)
    at jni_2.Min2.main(Min2.java:14)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please post the (C) prototype of the native function

Answer (score 1):

JNI does not work that way.

It appears that you're trying to load the Windows runtime library (`kernel32`) and invoke its [`FlushProcessWriteBuffers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You can't do that with JNI. With JNI, you can only invoke specially-written native functions, coded and linked according to [the JNI specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html).

In order to invoke `FlushProcessWriteBuffers` via JNI, you will need to write a JNI-compatible wrapper function in C (or whatever), compile that to produce a library, load that library, and then make the native call. The wrapper function can then call `FlushProcessWriteBuffers`.

You could also look into using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna#readme), which works a bit like a generic wrapper function, allowing you to call any native function without having to write your own wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to use JNI to call a Windows system function.

For this to work, you'd need to write your own C wrapper that would conform to the JNI naming conventions and that would internally call `FlushProcessWriteBuffers()`.

Alternatively, take a look at [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).

Comment: What's better/different than Tom Anderson answer?

Comment: @Aubin: We both came up with similar answers at almost exactly the same time. This happens on SO all the time, especially when the answer is fairly obvious.